# How to Attach an existing Attachment to a Post?

Tags: wordpress

I have a saved Attachment (it is stored in db as a Post of type "attachment"). It is not attached to any Post. How can I attach it to some Post (or Page)?

Using WordPress 3.5.1

**Edit:**
Using PHP, of course.

Comment: You might be able to find more answers for this type of question if you try asking on [WordPress Answers SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Do you mean attach it in admin area? or using a code? thank you for giving more details so that we understand and learn with you

Comment: @summea I guess you are right, thanks. Can a question be moved somehow?

Comment: I think there is a way for questions to be moved... but in this case, it might just be easier to copy/paste this question and ask it in the [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) area :)